# Weblogic JMS Bridge weblogic.transaction.RollbackException

Tags: jms, weblogic12c

We have a bridge configured in weblogic A server which picks the messages from another weblogic server B queue and put it in the Weblogic A queue.

However suddenly we are getting the below exception in the wevblogic log and bridge is unable to pick the messages from Weblogic Server B queue.

```
<May 16, 2018 9:30:54 AM IST> <Warning> <MessagingBridge> <BEA-200026>
<Bridge "AAA" encountered problems in one of its adapters or underlying
 systems. It stopped transferring messages and will try to reconnect to
 the adapters shortly. (The exception that occurred was 
weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Aborting prepare because the 
following resources could not be assigned: WLStore_WLS_AdminServerPLT)>
```

I tried below solution however none of them worked.

1) Cleared the Persistence Store from Weblogic A console and bounced the server

2) Created another Persistence store in Weblogic A and used newly created Persistence stored in JMS server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after we cleared all the pending messages from Weblogic Server B queue. I was not able to identify the specific message in the queue which was causing the error.